# How would I generate / parse this RESTful url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-routing

I'm new to MVC, being RESTful, and CodeIgniter. I'm trying to get into them in my spare time, so this is largely an academic question.  I'm trying to build a URL that will display the availability of a particular hotel room, for a particular hotel.  I figured the RESTful way to do this would be the following:

```
http://url/Hotel/2/RoomAvailability/3/
```

- "Hotel" is the controller
- "2" is the hotel ID
- "RoomAvailability" is the Method
- "3" is the Room ID

How would I set up my controller in codeigniter to handle this? Currently I'm thinking I could do either of the following:

- Do something with mod_rewrite to redirect to the RoomAvailability() method
- Do something with the index() method and redirect to the RoomAvailability() method

Really this is a pretty generic question, as I just want to be able to do the following:

`http://url/model/method-argument/method-name/more-method-arguments`

I'm honestly having a hard time coming up with search terms to find out what to use (other than RESTful and CodeIgniter, which havent been too helpful0.

I'm really just looking for guidance; not for someone to write my controller for me. Also, if this URL that I'm going for is horrible, and not RESTful at all; please feel free to point out a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this url set up:

```
http://url/hotel/method/hotel_id/room_id
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
class Hotel extends Controller {

 function RoomAvailability() {
   $hotel = url_segment(3);
   $room = url_segment(4);
   do_magic();
 }

}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but is this considered restful?  I thought to be considered restful you would have to have something in the order I had it.  As in "a Hotel's (this hotel id) Room's (this room id) availability".  I may be completely wrong though.

Comment: well in that case, using the routes is probably the best way. routes are very easy to set up in codeigniter. $route["hotel/:num/RoomAvailability/:num"] = 'RoomAvailabilityClass'; might get you going

Comment: Changed the accepted answer, that route is EXACTLY what I needed, it works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the CI User Guide, specifically the part on routing.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html